# Multiple Coins from Single Mint Example in PyMC

Tags: bayesian, pymc

Trying to learn PyMC by transferring some of the models from the book "Doing Bayesian Data Analysis" (Kruschke). One basic example (from Ch. 9) is to assume a set of coins is distributed according to `p~Bern(theta)` where theta comes from a `Beta` distribution (the "mint") with fixed parameters. Here's how I have coded it up (in PyMC2):

```
import pymc as pm
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sbn
from pymc.Matplot import plot as mcplot

from pymc import Bernoulli, Beta, Gamma

flips = [[True, False, False, False],
         [False, False, False, True],
         [True, False, False, False],
         [False, False, False, False]]

mint = Beta('mint', alpha=2, beta=2)

coin0 = Bernoulli('coin0', p=mint, value=flips[0], observed=True)
coin1 = Bernoulli('coin1', p=mint, value=flips[1], observed=True)
coin2 = Bernoulli('coin2', p=mint, value=flips[2], observed=True)
coin3 = Bernoulli('coin3', p=mint, value=flips[3], observed=True)

mcmc = pm.MCMC([mint, coin0, coin1, coin2, coin3])
mcmc.sample(iter=10000, burn=1000)

mcmc.summary()
mint:

    Mean             SD               MC Error        95% HPD interval
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    [[ 0.253]]       [[ 0.096]]       [[ 0.002]]       [ 0.074  0.439]


    Posterior quantiles:

    2.5             25              50              75             97.5
     |---------------|===============|===============|---------------|
    [[ 0.089]]       [[ 0.183]]      [[ 0.242]]     [[ 0.318]]    [[ 0.46]]
```

This seems to have worked, but what I'm wondering is how do I get the theta values for each coin? I assume there should be samples generated from the posterior distribution for each coin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by `theta`, since there is no theta in your model. Are you referring to the coin-specific probabilities (which are here represented by `mint`)? You have specified a single probability for all the coins, rather than 4 probabilities. Try modifying your `mint` parameter to:

```
mint = Beta('mint', alpha=2, beta=2, size=4)
```

which will specify a vector-valued stochastic of size 4.

Comment: Yes, I mean I'm interested in finding the theta for each individual coin. Your suggestion works and makes sense. The only other modification I needed was to set p=mint[i] for each coin. Thanks!